# Importing Open Api 3.0 yaml to Postman 7.1

Tags: yaml, postman, openapi, json-api, openapi-generator

I'd like to import an open-api 3.0 yaml file into postman, v. 7.1.1.

I am generating OpenApi 3.0 docs in Laravel using darkaonline/l5-swagger. The generated open-api 3.0 yaml file produces an error-free output when pasted into editor.swagger.io. The api is being written in accordance with json:api spec (or is intended to be). 
When the file is imported to postman (v 7.1.1) this error is generated : "Error while importing Open API 3.0: Could not import" All the documentation I've read says that postman now supports open api 3.0. I tried loading  OpenApi 3.0 yaml examples from Zircote's github, and they imported just fine. They are much less complex than our docs, though.
 Code excerpt: Warning this is a lot, but I feel like I needed to give enough context(It's actually a small chunk of the full doc--the file is 2000 lines long):

````
info:
  title: 'NAME OF MY API'
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  -
    url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
paths:
   /accounts:
    get:
      tags:
        - accounts
      summary: 'list accounts'
      operationId: 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\AccountsController::index'
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'A list of accounts'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                required:
                  - data
                properties:
                  data:
                    description: 'Show all accounts for this request.'
                    type: array
                    items:
                      properties:
                        type:
                          type: string
                        id:
                          type: string
                        attributes:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/account'
                        relationships:
                          properties:
                            persons:
                              type: array
                              items:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/relationship'
                          type: object
                        links:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/relationship/properties/links'
                      type: object
                  meta:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/meta'
                  links:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/links'
                type: object
        401:
          description: 'Unauthorized access'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        404:
          description: 'No records found'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
      servers:
        -
          url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
    post:
      tags:
        - accounts
      summary: 'new account'
      operationId: 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\AccountsController::store'
      responses:
        201:
          description: 'Successful save'
        401:
          description: 'Unauthorized access'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        400:
          description: 'Bad request, save failed'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
      servers:
        -
          url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
  '/accounts/{id}':
    get:
      tags:
        - accounts
      summary: 'get one account'
      operationId: 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\AccountsController::show'
      parameters:
        -
          name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'An account object'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  type:
                    description: 'Display the specified resource.'
                    type: string
                  id:
                    description: 'Display the specified resource.'
                    type: string
                  attributes:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/account'
                  relationships:
                    description: 'Display the specified resource.'
                    properties:
                      persons:
                        description: 'Display the specified resource.'
                        type: array
                        items:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/relationship'
                    type: object
                  links:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/relationship/properties/links'
                type: object
        401:
          description: 'Unauthorized access'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        404:
          description: 'Record not found'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
      servers:
        -
          url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
    delete:
      tags:
        - accounts
      summary: 'remove account'
      operationId: 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\AccountsController::destroy'
      parameters:
        -
          name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'An account object'
        401:
          description: 'Unauthorized access'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        405:
          description: 'Method not allowed'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        400:
          description: 'Bad request, save failed'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
      servers:
        -
          url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
    patch:
      tags:
        - accounts
      summary: 'update account'
      operationId: 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\AccountsController::update'
      parameters:
        -
          name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'An account object'
        401:
          description: 'Unauthorized access'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
        400:
          description: 'Bad request, save failed'
          content:
            application/vnd.api+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/error-response'
      servers:
        -
          url: 'https://api.API.com/v1'
components:
  schemas:
    account:
      title: 'account object'
      description: 'A single account object.'
      required:
        - ur_account_id
        - name
        - address1
        - city
        - state
        - zip
        - country_code
        - phone
        - email
      properties:
        _id:
          description: 'Unique identifier to include in path to get a single record.'
          type: string
        ur_account_id:
          description: 'The unique account ID.'
          type: string
        name:
          description: 'The name associated with the account'
          type: string
        address_1:
          description: 'The street address for the account.'
          type: string
        address_2:
          description: 'The Suite number, PO Box Number, Floor Number, etc, for the account.'
          type: string
        city:
          description: 'The city the account is resides in.'
          type: string
        state:
          description: 'The two letter abbreviation of the state the account resides in'
          type: string
        zip:
          description: 'The Postal Code the account resides in.'
          type: string
        country_code:
          description: 'Country code associated with the account.'
          type: string
        phone:
          description: 'The phone number associated with the account.'
          type: string
        phone_alpha:
          description: 'The phone number associated with the account.'
          type: string
        email:
          description: 'Email associated with the account'
          type: string
        require_po:
          description: 'Whether the account requires a PO.'
          type: string
        status:
          description: 'Status of current account'
          type: boolean
tags:
  -
    name: accounts
    description: 'Everything about accounts'
    externalDocs:
      description: 'Find out more'
      url: 'http://admin.API.com/documents' ```
````

Comment: On line 8, `/accounts` have one extra space before it, which messes up YAML indentation and will cause parsing errors.

Comment: Hi Helen! Thanks for your response. That indentation error was only due to copying and pasting. The indentation is correct in my file---When I altered it in the swagger editor, it threw an error.

Comment: If your OpenAPI definition is valid according to Swagger Editor, then it's probably a Postman issue. File a ticket with their support.

Comment: Thanks, Helen. I will do that. I did isolate the issue to where path variables are declared (e.g. line 93). I compared to other open-api 3.0 yaml files' path var declarations, and as far as i can tell it's the same. (With the exception of the single quotes, description prop, which I adjusted resulting in no change.) If I change the `in` prop to `query` it actually imports fine, although it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that within each path object’s servers object, I defined only the base URL, assuming for some reason that the base URL would be concatenated with the path. If you define a server object within the path object, you have to use the FULL URL for the endpoint. It was giving me errors specifically with /{id} endpoints because I defined a path variable that not present in the servers object

Comment: Can you share the final format that was accepted by Postman.
I am also having an issue importing endpoint with path parameter. I tried server object in path object with different combinations but no success.

Comment: @thomasdietrichandbradley Could you please share your updated yaml file.
I am trying to import using opnapi.json file in postman and  postman is showing the same issue i.e. "Error while importing: format is not recognize". I have tried with passing full url. ex:  "servers": ["url": "FULL_URL" ]

But it is failed with the same error.